# How to Perform Physical file Delete Operation when gridview row deleted using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I'm new to Grid View ,
I got some Filenames  in Grid view form Sql Data Source ,And if I Delete that row ,The Physical File also  should deleted which is Existed on some Other Folder.
This is My Code I've Tried..

```
        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
               Control control=e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];

               String Filename = e.Row.Cells[2].ToString();

                if (control is LinkButton)
                {
                    ((LinkButton)control).OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you Sure you want to delete? this Cannot be undone')";

                 if((File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Content/MainContent/BulkDataContent/" + Filename))))
                     {
                    File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/Content/MainContent/BulkDataContent/" + Filename));
                     }
                }
```

But the Problem is ,When I Delete one File from Grid View ,One Row is Deleted From Grid view and All Physical Files Are Deleted Form the Folder... It looping Till the end ..
Help me to over come this problem...
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: where is link button click event?

Answer (score 1):

Updated Ans

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
               Control control=e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];

               String Filename = e.Row.Cells[2].ToString();

                if (control is LinkButton)
                {
                    ((LinkButton)control).OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you Sure you want to delete? this Cannot be undone')";
    //write here your Delete query/Procedure


    if((File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Content/MainContent/BulkDataContent/" + Filename))))
                 {
                File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/Content/MainContent/BulkDataContent/" + Filename));
                 }
            }
```

Comment: This GridView has Auto Genarated Delete Button , so I think no need to Write Delete query  ,now I wanna Delete the Exact File form above path,On which user clicks